# How to move file to error directory if file name patter does not match with Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to move files to error directory if file name patter does not match provided regex. I have a `RegexFileFilter<T>` class which implements `GenericFileFilter<T>`. This is the accept method.

```
    public boolean accept(GenericFile<T> file) {
        Matcher matcher = getFileNameRegexp().matcher(file.getFileName());
        boolean matches = matcher.matches();
        if (!matches) {
            log.error("File named [{}] is not imported because it doesn't matches the expected pattern: [{}].", file.getFileName(), getFileNameRegexp().pattern());
        }
        return matches;
    }
```

Problem is that if matches = `false` the file will be taken once again when scheduler restarts it. I have tried to throw an exception after logging error

```
throw new PatternSyntaxException("File name doesn't match expected pattern ", getFileNameRegexp().toString(), -1);
```

And created configuration which should move file to errorLocation if exception `PatternSyntaxException` is thrown

```
onException(PatternSyntaxException.class)
                    .useOriginalMessage()
                    .handled(true)
                    .to(getFTPErrorLocation());
```

The problem is that when I throw exception Camel lib will eat that exception and exclude file which threw that exception. Is there a way to bypass it or maybe other way of using an exclude to move file?

I have also tried adding it URI format
`&scheduler=spring&scheduler.cron=0+0/1+*+*+*+?&readLock=rename&move=processed&disconnect=true&filter=#fileFilter&exclude=.*(\.GL1025\.).*&move=error`
But it did not help. Any suggestions?

***Edit***

Here is my route part.

```
    public void configure() {
        addFileAlreadyProcessedExceptionHandler();
        addEmptyFileExceptionHandler();
        addFailedFileTransformationExceptionHandler();
        addFailedFileNamePatternExceptionHandler();
        addTransactionProcessExceptionHandler();
        addFileDownloadRoute();
        from(getLocalFileSystemDownloadLocation())
                .onCompletion()
                .bean(CreditCardImportLogServiceBean.class)
                .process(fileImportStatisticProcessor)
                .end()
                .transacted()
                .routeId(getRouteId())
                .bean(CreditCardStatusServiceBean.class)
                .to(xsltProcess)
                .process(transactionCounterProcessor)
                .split(xPathBuilder)
                .convertBodyTo(String.class, "ISO-8859-1")
                .unmarshal(jaxb)
                .bean(ImportLogProcessor.class)
                .bean(CurrencyCodeServiceBean.class)
                .bean(CCTransactionConverterProcessor.class)
                .bean(CreditCardTypeMapperServiceBean.class)
                .bean(CreditCardImporterServiceBean.class);
    }

    protected void addFileDownloadRoute() {
        from(getFtpConfiguration())
                .routeId(getDownloadRouteId())
                .transacted()
                .to(getLocalFileSystemDownloadLocation());
    }

    protected void addFailedFileNamePatternExceptionHandler() {
        onException(PatternSyntaxException.class)
                .useOriginalMessage()
                .handled(true)
                .to(getFTPErrorLocation());
    }
```

Every other exception works correctly, the only part that does not work is `addFailedFileNamePatternExceptionHandler` or at least does not work as I intend it to work.

Comment: can you paste the complete route code

Comment: @pvpkiran added rout code. Don't see the point of adding full class file as everything else is working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this, as the file is not accepted, and therefore not really processed by Camel, unless you turn on bridge error handler on the consumer.

So instead you may want to use the filter EIP pattern afterwards where you check the file name, and then throw an exception if it fails etc.

Comment: Was thinking so that It might not be possible. Decided to remove the filter and do filtering after importing file.